# Initialize container from Control

Tags: c#, controls, containers

I have this code:

```
    public class Configuration{

        public Control container;

        public Configuration()
        {
            container = new Control();

        }
    }
```

and i want to initialize in the constructor of Configuration the contrainer of control, i wanna be able to add componentes to the container like this:

```
container.Container.Add(someComponente);
```

With the assurance that the Container has already been initialized.

How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "lazy-loading" technique.

```
public class Configuration {
    private Control container;
    public Control Container {
        get {
            var result = this.container;
            if ( null == result ) {
                this.container = result = new Container();
            }
        }
        set { this.container = value; }
    }
}

// ... elsewhere ...
var cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.Container.Controls.Add(new Button());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Loaded event handler to execute your code:

```
container.Loaded += (s, e) =>
{
    // do something
};
```

This example is using an anonymous method, but of course you can use the usual handler as well.